# Is there a way to concatenate a piece of string to all string in a collection?

Tags: c#, .net, string, generics, collections

## Is there an easier way to concatenate a piece of string to every items in a `List`?

#### For example

```cs
string s = "World"
List<string> ls = new List<string>
{
    "Hello",
    "Hi"
};
```

#### Will it be possible...

to come out with a `List<string>` that contains

```
HelloWorld
HiWorld
```

without introducing a new variable and/or using a loop?

Thanks.

Comment: How would you apply something to every element of a list _without_ a loop? Even LINQ which can do this in a 1-liner is still a loop under the hood!

Comment: ls = ls.Select(x => x + "World").ToList();

Comment: FWIW: `var newList = ls.Select(item => item + s).ToList()`